# How to display single row against each groupBy rdlc report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, wptoolkit

I am trying to display aggrgated data in my rdlc report. I have grouped data by a particular field by

```
Add Group -> Parent Group -> Group By: Field Name
```

All data shows up as I want against each group. Now I want to display count of records against each particular group. So I added a column to the right on group and added the following expression

```
=Count(Fields!TestPackNo.Value, "ModuleNo")
```

This correctly displays count of records against each group but the problem is # of rows that are appearing against each group is repeating. I want only one # (count of TestPack NOs against each Module) to appear. How do i do that?

Comment: Can you include a screen capture or a text-based example of what you're seeing?

Comment: Add group by "TestPackNo" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add this formula to the total outside of the group.